# Unity interception doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, unity-container, unity-interception

I use unity as my aop framework, but it doesn't work as expected. Please check my code below.

```
container.RegisterType<IPerson, Person>(new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
    new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IPlay>(), container.Resolve<IEat>()));

var person = container.Resolve<IPerson>();
person.Play();
person.Eat();
((IAnimal)person).Sleep();
Console.Read();

public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input,
       GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoking method {0} begin", input.MethodBase));
    var result = getNext()(input, getNext);
    if (result.Exception != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} throws exception", input.MethodBase);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoking method {0} end", input.MethodBase));
    }
    return result;
}
```

When container.Resolve() and ((IAnimal)person) run, the behavior also executed, and print out

> Invoking method System.Type GetType() begin
>
> Invoking method System.Type GetType() end

I want the log only execute when I call method explicitly. how to prevent it?

Comment: Not very clear what you trying to achieve, but I suspect you are looking for `new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>()` instead of `new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>()`.

Comment: I want all of the method in my class could be logged, so I use TransparentProxyInterceptor instead of InterfaceInspector. You can see, my interception behavior logged the method's name. But, the resolve method and force convert operation don't have method name, so it print out System.Type GetType()

Comment: I don't know - are you sure that you get false calls (GetType is method of your class - so if proxy really can hijack all calls you may be getting valid calls)... Note that it is somewhat strange to resolve interface and expect more unrelated interfaces to be exposed (I get why you trying to do that... but maybe you can refactor your code to have factory resolving proper interfaces instead or something else to avoid wrapping all methods...)

Comment: But if the existing class already implement more than 1 interfaces?